# convert xml (android source) to pdf

Tags: android, xml, pdf, apache-fop

```
public void onClick(View v)     
{switch(v.getId())

    { case R.id.button1:

        try {


            // Setup directories
            File baseDir = new File("res/layout");
            File outDir = new File(baseDir, "/sdcard");
            outDir.mkdirs();

            // Setup input and output files
            File xmlfile = new File(baseDir, "activity_main.xml");
            File xsltfile = new File(baseDir, "test.xsl");
            File pdffile = new File(outDir, "ResultXML2PDF.pdf");   
                                    // configure fopFactory as desired
            FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

            FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
            // configure foUserAgent as desired

            // Setup output
            OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
            out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);

            try {
                // Construct fop with desired output format
                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

                // Setup XSLT
                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));

                // Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet
                transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");

                // Setup input for XSLT transformation
                Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);

                // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                transformer.transform(src, res);
            } finally {
                out.close();
        }

            System.out.println("Success!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        }
}
```

---

### Heading

i want to convert my xml file including my view to pdf .. my android application must generat this pdf . i use code bellow but when i click on the generator button , the application is closed sudunely , and no file pdf in the sdcard (my xml and xsl file are in layout repertory).

Comment: Have you tried checking logcat? Perhaps you could recreate the crash and post the resulting logcat here.

Comment: if i put "OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);" inside the try cach the application. stopped but if i put it out ,a pdf file that have size of 0 kb apears and the application stooped again ..... so i guess that the try catch dont work correctely or somethig like that ... :s

Comment: i want know , when the application is installed ,  the project files paths are the same that when they are in the workspace ? (i know that the "project name = root "

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/Gkemon/Android-XML-to-PDF-Generator) to make it easy to do within a few lines of code -

```
 PdfGenerator.getBuilder()
                        .setContext(context)
                        .fromLayoutXMLSource()
                        .fromLayoutXML(R.layout.layout_print,R.layout.layout_print)
                        .setFileName("Test-PDF")
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look on this link:

https://github.com/HendrixString/Android-PdfMyXml

Instructions

1. create XML layouts

First create XML layouts. give it dimensions in pixels (and for all it's sub views) and proportions according landscape or portrait according to ratio 1:1.41.

page1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="2115px"
            android:layout_height="1500px"
            android:background="@color/white">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_hello"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="27px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="6px"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

you can create as many as pages/templates as you need.

2. Implement a View renderer

implement your View renderer by extending AbstractViewRenderer or by anonymously instantiating it and injecting the layout id. the initView(View view) will supply you an inflated View automatically. There are other options but I wont cover it now.

```
AbstractViewRenderer page = new AbstractViewRenderer(context, R.layout.page1) {
private String _text;

public void setText(String text) {
    _text = text;
}

@Override
protected void initView(View view) {
    TextView tv_hello = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_hello);
     tv_hello.setText(_text);
}
};

// you can reuse the bitmap if you want
page.setReuseBitmap(true);
```

3. Build the PDF document

Use PdfDocument or PdfDocument.Builder to add pages and render and run it all at background with progress bar.

```
    PdfDocument doc            = new PdfDocument(ctx);

// add as many pages as you have
doc.addPage(page);

doc.setRenderWidth(2115);
doc.setRenderHeight(1500);
doc.setOrientation(PdfDocument.A4_MODE.LANDSCAPE);
doc.setProgressTitle(R.string.gen_please_wait);
doc.setProgressMessage(R.string.gen_pdf_file);
doc.setFileName("test");
doc.setInflateOnMainThread(false);
doc.setListener(new PdfDocument.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(File file) {
        Log.i(PdfDocument.TAG_PDF_MY_XML, "Complete");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        Log.i(PdfDocument.TAG_PDF_MY_XML, "Error");
    }
});

doc.createPdf(ctx);
```

or use PdfDocument.Builder

```
new PdfDocument.Builder(ctx).addPage(page).filename("test").orientation(PdfDocument.A4_MODE.LANDSCAPE)
                         .progressMessage(R.string.gen_pdf_file).progressTitle(R.string.gen_please_wait).renderWidth(2115).renderHeight(1500)
                         .listener(new PdfDocument.Callback() {
                             @Override
                             public void onComplete(File file) {
                                 Log.i(PdfDocument.TAG_PDF_MY_XML, "Complete");
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onError(Exception e) {
                                 Log.i(PdfDocument.TAG_PDF_MY_XML, "Error");
                             }
                         }).create().createPdf(this);
```